# how to use .htaccess file in our HTML website? for remove page extention from website

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a HTML website and I want to remove pages extension (.html) from my website. I've used .htaccess file but I don't know how to use .htaccess file in my website's page.
Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

No need to add code in any page.Create .htacess file with above content & add file to the root folder of your site(for example, /home/domains/domain.com/htdocs/)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^.\ ]+\.)+html(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)*index/?$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^([^.]+\.)+([a-z0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1.html[L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Change whole content of .htaccess with above one ,I hope above will helpful.!

Comment: Kindly do not post multiple answers, use the EDIT link and update your answer with the new content.